# IE7 CSS Grouping

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some classes that are grouped. However in IE7 and lower it doesn't implement any of the classes in the group. It just seems to ignore them:

```
#subnav a,
#subnav span {
    /* css here */
}
```

And the html:

```
<div id="subnav">
    <ul class="depth-1">
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="someLink.html">Some Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="anotherLink.html">Another Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Header</span>
            <ul class="depth-2">
                <li>
                    <a href="google.com.au">Google</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is CSS grouping not supported in IE7 and below or is something else causing this to happen?

Thanks

Comment: CSS selector grouping is a fundamental feature of CSS and is supported in IE3+. We'll need to see your HTML, or better yet a test case. I'm sure something else is causing this.

Comment: Ensure you haven't misspelt `subnav`, ensure it *is* an id and not a class, and ensure the `a` and `span` are a descendent of the `#subnav`.

Comment: Thanks, now i know its me. See added html code.

Comment: You should make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a few things here:

1. make sure this rule group is last in the css stylesheet to ensure that no other styles are overwriting these ones
2. make the selectors as specific as possible, to ensure the elements are targeted.  So, instead of `#subnav a`, try `div#subnav ul.depth-1 li.selected a`
3. make sure the styles can be applied to those particular elements.  `a` and `span` are inline elements and do not accept all styles.